# PHPMyAdmin page error after change MySQL port number in WAMP

Tags: mysql, iis, phpmyadmin, wamp, port

I have IIS installed with an existing MySQL version on my server computer. Now I want to install WAMP to host magento sites.

After I installed WAMP and changed the apache port from 80 to 8090, all the magento sites siting on wamp server works fine. But all my IIS php sites cannot connect to the old MySQL database.

So I was requested to change the port of the new MySQL in WAMP.

I changed the my.ini file with the new port number 3307, then I restarted wamp service. The server icon is green, but when I visit the phpMyAdmin page, I got an error message saying "#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".

I searched on goolge and changed the config.inc.php file with port = 3307, restarted service again. But I still got the same error.

Is there anything else needs to be changed to get it working on the phpMyAdmin page? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things you can try.

1. Have you refreshed your Browser Cache ( CTRL + F5 )
2. Did you change the correct section of `my.ini`

Locate this section of `my.ini` and chnage the port number there

```
# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
port = 3307
```

Also locate this section

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
port = 3307
```

and change the port there as well.

Restart MySQL and now phpMyAdmin should have a server to talk to. Also if you use the command line access to mysql it will also be looking at the correct server.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change port in the phpMyAdmin config file as well.

Locate the file config.default.php in the libraries folder in the phpmyadmin folder.

Locate this section

```
/**

 MySQL port - leave blank for default port

 @global string $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']

*/

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3307';
```

and enter the port there as well.
Then restart the MySQL service and phpMyAdmin should work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Wampserver and had to change this in `config.inc.php` as well

```
/* $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $wampConf['mysqlPortUsed']; */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3308';
```

I came across another post that said 3307 is reserved for Maria so use 3308.